# How to make use of Boost.Log?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I am currently considering to use `Boost.Log` for logging purposes. It looks quite interesting, but I am not quite sure yet, how I am supposed to manage logger objects.

As far as I can see, there are the following options:

1. Using one global logger object.
2. Using one logger object per class by using `Boost.Log`'s label mechanism.
3. Using one logger object per object (either by using composition or sub-typing).

I have the following questions:

- What are the benefits of the individual approaches? The `Boost.Log` manual says that the last approach is superior, but I did not understand why.
- Which approach keeps the syntactic overhead of logging at a minimum? Or do you make use of any techniques in order to reduce the syntactic overhead? For example, I would like to avoid initializing the logger object from each constructor, but unfortunately constructor delegation is not an option yet.
- Do you have any other suggestions on integrating `Boost.Log` into an application or writing a new one that makes use of `Boost.Log`?